# Mac OS PackageMaker .app bundle not being installed?

Tags: macos, packagemaker

I'm making an application installer with PackageMaker, and one of the resources I've added to the install is the .app bundle. Now my finished installer is installing all components of the application except for the .app bundle itself. Has anyone experienced this before? If you need any more info I'll happily provide it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please refer to 
http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=511640

-> deselect Allow Relocation in the Components section for the application

-> If the bundle identifier in your Info.plist file is com.yourcompany.MySampleApp then make sure to use the same string "com.yourcompany.MySampleApp" in the organization section of the Package installer properties.

Hope these changes should install your .app bundle.